# iCloud Drive stuck with items 47 items uploading and 6 items downloading

Tags: macos, mac, icloud, finder

My iCloud Drive has been bugged for the past week, I've tried spamming killall bird, disabling iCloud Drive, deleting iCloud caches, but nothing. It always get stuck at x amount of items uploading and downloading. I have nearly 2 TB stuff in iCloud and they don't fit on my Mac, so if I untick Optimize Mac Storage, it can break iCloud Drive for multiple days.

Apple support can't help since my Mac is old, but I am running the latest macOS 12.3.1. Is there anything I can do without losing files?

I've also noticed that if I could find where these files that are stuck are located, just opening the folder has before continued the download. But I do not know where could the files be, is there a way to check that?

Comment: Have you restarted your computer? That usually fixes it for me when it's stuck. Restart it, leave it plugged in and awake for a few hours.

Comment: @Ezekiel I've done that countless times